# Select only IDs where a certain column only contains a certain value

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have the following table example:

Input:

```
ID | event_type | event_value | time
---+------------+-------------+-------
1  |     A      |   sinus     | 14:23  <- select ID = 1
1  |     A      |   sinus     | 15:22
1  |     B      |   low WC    | 15:22
1  |     A      |   sinus     | 16:22
1  |     C      |   RX OK     | 17:22
.
2  |     A      |   sinus     | 14:23  
2  |     A      |  arrhytm    | 15:22 <- DON'T select ID = 2
2  |     B      |   low WC    | 15:22
2  |     A      |   sinus     | 16:22
.
3  |     A      |   sinus     |  12:32 <- select ID = 3
3  |     B      |   WC ok     |  13:23
3  |     C      |   ph ok     |  13:40
3  |     A      |   sinus     |  13:33
3  |     A      |   sinus     |  14:22
```

Output:

```
ID 
---
 1
 3
```

I want to select only the IDs where ALL of the event_type A entries, for a given ID, have event_value = 'sinus'.
How can I do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, HAVING

Comment: Hint#2: `exists`, `not exists`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the boolean aggregate [`bool_and()`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
with my_table(id, event_type, event_value, time) as (
values
    (1, 'A', 'sinus', '14:23'),
    (1, 'A', 'sinus', '15:22'),
    (1, 'B', 'low WC', '15:22'),
    (1, 'A', 'sinus', '16:22'),
    (1, 'C', 'RX OK', '17:22'),
    (2, 'A', 'sinus', '14:23'),
    (2, 'A', 'arrhytm', '15:22'),
    (2, 'B', 'low WC', '15:22'),
    (2, 'A', 'sinus', '16:22')
)

select id
from my_table
group by id
having bool_and(event_type <> 'A' or event_value = 'sinus')

 id 
----
  1
(1 row)
```

Alternatively with `WHERE` clause:

```
select id
from my_table
where event_type = 'A'
group by id
having bool_and(event_value = 'sinus')
```

Comment: Can you explain how the bool_and works? the 'or' within it confused me :)
Many thanks!

Comment: This means: check whether all rows with a given id have `event_type <> 'A'` **or** (otherwise) `event_value = 'sinus'`. You can use `where` alternatively.

Answer (score 1):

Lacking a bit of specifics in terms of table names to be precise, but you appear to want to check for a lack of existence of anything else for that ID / Event_type.

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourTable a
WHERE a.event_type = 'A' 
AND not exists (SELECT 1 
                  FROM yourTable b 
                  WHERE a.ID = b.ID 
                  AND a.event_type = b.event_type 
                  AND b.event_value <> 'sinus')
```

The results then need to be grouped / aggregated based on what your needed output is, it was not shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` clause :

```
select t.id
from table t
where t.event_type = 'A'
group by t.id
having min(t.event_value) = max(t.event_value) and min(t.event_value) = 'sinus';
```

Comment: This works!
I can't mark this answer as the best one because user klin was faster (and it seems to be more clean), but many thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
 Select id from  table 
 where event_type ='A' 
 group by id 
 having 
 min(event_value) = 'sinus'
 and 
 max(event_value)  = 'sinus'
```

Comment: his works! I can't mark this answer as the best one because user klin was faster (and it seems to be more clean), but many thanks for your time! :)